# My dropdown isn't working properly and I don't know the the problem

Tags: php, pdo, while-loop, fetch

I wanted to make a dropdown so I decided to use while loop and fetch all id from the table in my database.

```
<select class = "form-control form-control-sm">

<?php 

$sql = "SELECT bBall_id FROM basketball_team";
$cmd = $db->prepare($ql);
$cmd->execute();

while($row = $cmd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    $id = $row['bBall_id'];
    echo $id;
?>

<option value = "<?php echo $id;?>"><?php echo $id;?></option>    

<?php

}
?>
```

It doesn't work tho. My connection to my database is working perfectly fine btw.

Comment: @Alucard Nemesis why out of `<option>` tag you write `echo $id`?

Comment: Because I am using the $id as value